# how to change the address bar url from inside a react js component

Tags: reactjs

I am using the react js router to navigate around. Now my question is how can I change the url in address bar from inside a component?

Suppose I have url as follows: `https://websitename/loc/lib/12`, and I have a dropdown list with some numbers which when selected, it should change the url above, ie: the number after the /lib/`...`<--.

What is the best way to modify it? Do I have to change it by pushing the change up the component till it reaches the page where the react router is declared? Or should I change it direclty in the page by using window.location.href?

Information:

```
React version: 17.0.1
React-router-dom: 4.3.1
Using React js classes (not react hooks).
```

Answer (score 1):

See [navigating](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#navigating) in the documentation.

Get the [`navigate` function](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#navigate-function) from the `useNavigate` hook.

Since it is a hook you can get it directly in the component that renders the `<select>` element.

Then call it:

```
onChange={ event => navigate(`/loc/lib/${event.target.value}`) };
```

---

NB: This assumes React Router v6. It is a significant change over the equivalent functionality in old versions of React Router.

Comment: is there a way to do it without the hooks?

Answer (score -1):

Before react router v6: You can use `useHistory` from the `history` package, which you probably already have in use, and use e.g. `push` from the history object to go to a new location.

Comment: [`useHistory` has been removed](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory)

Comment: Oh, and everybody is on react router v6? Riiight…